# mysql update subquery set

Tags: mysql, sql, random, subquery

I couldn't find and couldn't produce a solution to this problem with SQL Mysql.
I want to update two columns of a table, and the origin of these values ​​are from another table, having to come randomly.
Here's a tentative example:

```
update table1 a1,
(select col1, col2 
 from table2  
 ORDER BY RAND() limit 1) a2
set a1.col1 = a2.col1, a1.col2 = a2.col2
where a1.col3 is not null;
```

From this form, the same value from table2 is always coming.

```
table1         |  table2
id  col1 col2  |  id col1 col2
1   aaa  bbb   |  1  xxx  yyy
2   ccc  ddd   |  2  www  ttt 
               |  3  uuu  vvv
```

I want the values ​​(col1, col2) from table 2 to be defined in table1 randomly (col1 and col2).

Without Limit 1, it is also being updated with the same record. As if there were 1 record in table2.

That is, for each line of the update, a subquery is made in the other table bringing a record randomly.

Comment: Of course the same value from table2 is coming. The subquery just returns 1 row because of `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  "having to come randomly" is not clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's pretty clear to me what they want. Each row of table1 where col3 is null should copy col1 and col2 from a random row of table2. But they want different random rows for each copy.

Comment: I.e. they want some kind of random join between the two tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But I'm stumped at how to do it, I think it requires your SQL magic.

Comment: That's what @Barmar said. I improved the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` and `row_number()`, but multiple times:

```
update table1 t1 join
       (select *, row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
        from table1 t1
       ) tt1
       on tt1.id = t1.id join
       (select *, row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
        from table2 t2
       ) t2
       on t2.seqnum = t1.seqnum
    set t1.col1 = t2.col1,
        t1.col2 = t2.col2;
```

This adds a sequence number defined randomly to the two tables and joins on that for the matching.  The extra join is to implement the `update`.